# execution time calculation

Tags: c#, algorithm

How to you calculate Execution time of your C#, Windows Application.

Are there any industry recognized methods?

Answer (score 9):

[`System`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aspx).[`Diagnostics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx).[`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).[`GetCurrentProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx).[`TotalProcessorTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.totalprocessortime.aspx) - the processor time used by the process (user mode and kernel mode). Use [`UserProcessorTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.userprocessortime.aspx) and [`PrivilegedProcessorTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.privilegedprocessortime.aspx) for separate values.

[`System`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aspx).[`Diagnostics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx).[`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).[`GetCurrentProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx).[`StartTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime.aspx) - yields in combination with [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx).[`Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) the running time of the process.

Use [`System`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aspx).[`Diagnostics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx).[`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to profile isolated tasks.

For advanced tasks you can use [`System`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aspx).[`Diagnostics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx).[`PerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in PostSharp (http://www.postsharp.org/).  You can have it run code when any method starts or stops.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GetTickCount() API function when you enter Main() and again when you're about to exit it, and take the difference between them to get the number of milliseconds your program took.